# Real time communication PC with PLC (protocol?)

Tags: real-time, protocols, communication, plc

Basically, I would like to creat my own piece of software something a la communication protocl between PC and PLC.

I would like to read real time values from PLC and display them in a table for example Data Base, OPC table, Excel and write to PLC from PC in real time mode as well.

The whole point is I would like to access this data via ethernet port. How I can do it ? I do not want to use 3rd party software. I want to create something my own.

Comment: Seems too vague to me.

Comment: what is the purpose of creating your own communication protocol? learning? then fine, look at socket and udp communication although disregarding all man-years put into existing protocols seems like a waste of time and effort.

Comment: You should take a look at OPC UA !

Comment: Are you wanting to write ladder logic to develop your own protocol, or are you wanting to talk to a specific brand of PLC and reverse-engineer their proprietary protocol, or are you looking to use Modbus/TCP or Modbus over UDP, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Choose any programming languages like C#,VB.NET and use opcdaauto.dll ,it is free dll for OPC Foundation members

You can easily get the live data from the OPC

or use dll provided by the OPC Server which you are using

Comment: sounds like he wants to do it from scratch, reinventing the wheel

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, OPC-UA is probably more preferable, otherwise, there are commercial libraries such as [InGear](http://ingeardrivers.com/) and open projects on GitHub.

If you actually want to implement your own low level drivers, they will depend on the PLC manufacturer. For example:

If you are working with Allen-Bradley, you will have to implement *Common Industrial Protocol* (CIP).

If you are working with Siemens, you will have to implement *S7 Communication* (S7comm or S7 for short).

If you search GitHub for various search terms related to Allen Bradley CIP and Siemens S7, you will find many starting points for communicating directly with these controllers.